# Thread Safety in Java Using Atomic Variables

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-8, thread-safety

I have a Java class, here's its code:

```
public class MyClass {
    private AtomicInteger currentIndex;
    private List<String> list;

    MyClass(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list; // list is initialized only one time in this constructor and is not modified anywhere in the class
        this.currentIndex = new AtomicInteger(0);
    }

    public String select() {
        return list.get(currentIndex.getAndIncrement() % list.size());
    }
}
```

Now my question:

Is this class really thread safe thanks to using an `AtomicInteger` only or there must be an addional thread safety mechansim to ensure thread-safety (for example locks)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `currentIndex.getAndIncrement()` is perfectly thread-safe. However, you need a change to your code to make it thread-safe in all circumstances.

The fields `currentIndex` and `list` need to be made `final` to achieve full thread-safety, even on unsafe publication of the reference to your `MyClass` object.

```
private final AtomicInteger currentIndex;
private final List<String> list;
```

In practice, if you always ensure that your `MyClass` object itself is safely published, for example if you create it on the main thread, before any of the threads that use it are started, then you don't need the fields to be `final`.

Safe publication means that the reference to the `MyClass` object itself is done in a way that has a guaranteed multi-threaded ordering in [the Java Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4).

It could be that:

- All threads that use the reference get it from a field that was initialized by the thread that started them, before their thread was started
- All threads that use the reference get it from a method that was synchronized on the same object as the code that set the reference (you have a synchronized getter and setter for the field)
- You make the field that contains the reference `volatile`
- It was in a `final` field if that final field was initialized as described in [section 17.5 of the JLS.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5)
- A few more cases the are not easily used to publish references

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But I can't understand what do you mean by "even on unsafe publication of the reference to your MyClass object.", can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 3):

I think your code contains two bugs.

First, normally when you receive an object from some unknown source like your constructor does, you make a defensive copy to be certain it is not modified outside of the class.

```
MyClass(List<String> list) {
    this.list = new ArrayList<String>( list );
```

So if you do this, do you now need to mutate that list anywhere inside the class?  If so, the method:

```
public String select() {
    return list.get(currentIndex.getAndIncrement() % list.size());
```

isn't atomic.  What could happen here is a thread call `getAndIncrement()` and then perform the modulus (`%`).  Then at that point if it's swapped out with another thread that removes an item from the list, the old limit of `list.size()` will no longer be valid.

I think there's nothing for it but to add `synchronized` to the whole method:

```
public synchronized String select() {
    return list.get(currentIndex.getAndIncrement() % list.size());
```

And the same with any other mutator.

(`final` as the other poster mentions is still required on the instance fields.)

Comment: I read this comment in the OP "list is initialized only one time in this constructor and is not modified anywhere in the class" as that the list is not modified after being assigned in the constructor.

Comment: Ah, missed that.  But now I have another problem.